# how to modify dataset for training

Tags: python, pytorch

I have a class:

```
class ToTensor(object):
"""Convert ndarrays in sample to Tensors."""

def __call__(self, sample):
    image, label = sample['image'], sample['label']

    # swap color axis because
    # numpy image: H x W x C
    # torch image: C x H x W
    image = image.transpose((2, 0, 1))
    #image = image.to(torch.float32)
    
    return {'image': torch.from_numpy(image),
            'label': torch.as_tensor(np.array(label).astype('float'))}
```

which produces data as two dicts with tensors:

- one tensor with image (features);
- another with labels (target).

[image]

This format is not accepted by the model (`resnet18`) when I try to train, because the expected format is a list of lists as in the image below:

[image]

I can change from the first format to second using code below:

```
trainlist = []
for i in trans_train_dataset:
    sample = i['image'], i['label']
    trainlist.append(sample)
```

but this is super slow (takes +1h after I adjusted memory). Another option I was thinking is to save dataset after conversion (using the code below), but it's too large for pickle and when I do it as txt later I got dataframe with tuples which I need to convert to torch again which isn't a good solution as well.

```
import csv

with open("trainlist4.csv", "w") as f:
    wr = csv.writer(f)
    wr.writerows(trainlist)
```

So, is there any fast way to convert a dataset to be readable by my model? Or, alternatively, how to save the dataset and load it in a readable format by the model.

Comment: Why don't you just modify the return of `ToTensor`?

Comment: Hi If I do:    trainlist =torch.as_tensor(np.array(trainlist).astype('float')) im getting ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'tensor([[[0.1451, 0.1451, 0.1451,...

Comment: I said "modify the return of `ToTensor`", your class. To return a tuple, instead of a dict.